# Separate one column in a table that has specific value into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have to separate one column in to table that has specific value into two columns, but I don't why my code gives me wrong numbers and it doesn't work properly.

My code is like this:

```
SELECT Pname
    , (SELECT sum(Pcount) FROM Personal_tbl WHERE Pregion = 'Germany') AS German
    , (SELECT sum(Pcount) FROM Personal_tbl WHERE Pregion = 'UK') AS UK
    , COUNT(FID) AS Total
FROM Personal_tbl
GROUP BY Pname
```

Input:

| Pname | Pregion | Pcount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ava | German | 10 |
| Ava | UK | 5 |

Output must be like this:

| Pname | German | UK | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ava | 10 | 5 | 15 |

Comment: `COUNT(FID)` returns the count of non-nulls in that column. Is that actually what you want?

Comment: If you add you sample data as DDL/DML it makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: you can use pivot in sql server [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: 'FID' doesn't exist? And `Germany` <> `German`. But you don't actually say what is wrong with the results your code returns?

Comment: It appears that the only errors in your code are spelling mistakes and counting an unmentioned column instead of summing Pcount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need write sub queries,  you can simply do it using conditional aggregation  like following.

```
SELECT pname
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN Pregion = 'German'
                THEN Pcount
            END) AS German
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN Pregion = 'UK'
                THEN Pcount
            END) AS uk
    ,SUM(Pcount) Total
FROM Personal_tbl
GROUP BY pname
```

Comment: Any reason for adding `ELSE 0`? I've always been curious as to reasons why to put it in or why not. I don't see a difference, just wondering.

Comment: So no preference either way?

Comment: null will not make any difference in sum so i feel specifying 0 is not required.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this sample code for pivot

```
SELECT Pname,[German],[UK] , [German]+[UK] as Total
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Personal_tbl
) AS sourcetable 
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(Pcount)
    FOR Pregion IN ([German],[UK])
) as pivottable
```

I created a table same as your structure and write sample pivot code

Select result of my sample

```
Pname  Pregion Pcount
------ ------- -----------
Ava    German  10
Ava    UK      5
```

And its my pivot sample code result

```
Pname German UK  Total
------------ --- -----
Ava   10     5   15
```